# Akka Actor Returning a Future to the Sender

Tags: akka

I have an Actor that responds to the sender by returning a Future[String]. Here is the code bit:

```
case PingTsdb => {
    sender ! someService.getVersion // returns a Future[String]
  }
```

The getVersion method returns a Future[String], but when I run this method, I get the following error:

```
Cannot cast scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise to java.lang.String
```

I understand that it is trying to cast the Future[String] into a String, but how do I get this actor to work? I can write an onComplete handler on the getVersion method return value, but is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured that out. I had to use the pipeTo method from the akka.ask pattern!

```
getTsVersion pipeTo sender
```

It was as simple as that!